# Change jquery mouseover to window mouseover

Tags: javascript

I want to change this (which gets a span name in my table):

```
$('span').on('mouseover', function () {
    if (this.id.match(/_zUserId/)) {
        alert(this.id);
    }
}
```

To use:

```
window.onmouseover=function(e) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get the span name from `e.target`. I don't know what to put after the `e.target` to get the span name.

Comment: What does `e.target.id` give you? You should be able to use `e.target` wherever you had `this`.

Comment: It is blank. This is how the table is set up for the item I want to mouseover. The table is created using a website creating program.
    <td data-name="zUser" style="white-space: nowrap;">
    <span id="el3_zUserId" class="tblCertifications_zUserId">
    <span>fname.lname@gmail.com</span>
    </span>
    </td>

Comment: I posted the answer for that, but I suggest to you to use the debugger to see all methods of an object, is the simplest way to check a real object in a real world. Use the console of chrome or firebug, stop the code in the function where your object is present, and check what the object expose.

Answer (score 0):

[Here the JSFiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/woot1ctf/)

```
window.onmouseover=function(e) {
    if (e.target.id=='mySpan') {
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: It must have something to do with how the table is constructed. The jquery function works correctly but e.target.id returns nothing using the window.onmouseover function.

Comment: @ready4data Can you post the HTML of your table ? and the actual JS you try to execute with onmouseover event ?